# Unique solution to ODE using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is:

> Use the Laplace transform to find a bounded solution on $(0,\infty)$ of the differential equation 
>   $$ty''(t) + (t-1)y'(t) - y(t) = 0$$ 
>   for which $y(t)$ tends to $1$ as $t$ tends to $0$ from above.
>
> Giving a brief explanation, state whether or not your solution is unique.

When I looked at it I thought that it would be unique, as putting $t=0$ into the ODE gives $-y'(0) - y(0) = 0$, and we also have the boundary condition given, so we have two conditions for a second order ODE so can determine both constants.

After solving though I obtained the solution $y(t) = c\exp(-t) + c(t-1)$ for a constant $c$, and knowing that $-y'(0) - y(0) = 0$ doesn't tell you anything about the constant $c$, so now I think the solution is not unique.

My questions are

1) How do you know whether the solution is unique?

2) Why does knowing $-y'(0) - y(0) = 0$ not tell you anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y(s) = \mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}$. Applying the Laplace transform, we have

$\mathcal{L}\{ty^{\prime \prime} + (t - 1)y^{\prime} - y\} = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \mathcal{L}\{ty^{\prime \prime}\} + \mathcal{L}\{ty^{\prime}\} - \mathcal{L}\{y^{\prime}\} - \mathcal{L}\{y\} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow$

$-\dfrac{d}{ds}[s^2Y(s) - sy(0) - y^{\prime}(0)] - \dfrac{d}{ds}[sY(s) - y(0)] - [sY(s) - y(0)] - Y(s) = 0$.

Using $y(0) = y^{\prime}(0) = 0$, we have $(s + 1)Y^{\prime}(s) = -Y \quad \Rightarrow \quad \ln Y = -\ln(s+1) + C \quad \Rightarrow \quad Y(s) = \dfrac{C}{s+1} $.

Reversing, have $y(t) = Ce^{-t}$. But, $1 = \displaystyle{\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}}y(t) = C$. Thus, $y(t) = e^{-y}$ is limited to $(0,+\infty)$.